# Tikz text overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code that plots three hyperbolas and a diagonal line.  The labels for the various curves display text which overlaps.  I am having trouble figuring out how to avoid the overlapping text.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arcsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
\begin{figure} 
\begin{center} \resizebox{!}{5 in}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%[domain=0:4] 
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (0,-3.9) grid (5.9,3.9);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-3.9) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$t$};

    \draw [color=red] plot[domain=-arcsinh(4):arcsinh(4)] ({cosh(\x)},{sinh(\x)}) node[above] {$r=1$};
    \draw [color=blue] plot[domain=-arcsinh(2):arcsinh(2)] ({2*cosh(\x)},{2*sinh(\x)}) node[midway,right] {$r=2$}; 
    \draw [color=green] plot[domain=-arcsinh(4/3):arcsinh(4/3)] ({3*cosh(\x)},{3*sinh(\x)}) node[below] {$r=3$}; 
    \draw [color=black] plot[domain=0:4/tanh(1)] ({\x},{tanh(1)*\x}) node[right] {$\omega=1$};  \filldraw ({cosh(1)},{sinh(1)}) circle
(2pt); \filldraw ({2*cosh(1)},{2*sinh(1)}) circle (2pt); \filldraw
({3*cosh(1)},{3*sinh(1)}) circle (2pt);   \end{tikzpicture}   }  
\caption{Polar Coordinates in a Minkowski Space}
    \label{fig:Hyperbolas} \end{center} \end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Your code doesn't work at all, because `arcsinh` isn't defined by TikZ/`pgf`. Have you defined that function yourself? If so, can you please turn your code into a complete example with the necessary definitions and packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `xshift` and `yshift` to refine your node positioning.

Moreover, use `\centering`, not `center` environment, within a figure.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={arcsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \resizebox{!}{5 in}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}%[domain=0:4] 
            \draw[very thin,color=gray] (0,-3.9) grid (5.9,3.9);
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
            \draw[->] (0,-3.9) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$t$};

            \draw [color=red] plot[domain=-arcsinh(4):arcsinh(4)] ({cosh(\x)},{sinh(\x)}) 
                node[yshift=-.1ex, xshift=-1.7em] {$r=1$};
            \draw [color=blue] plot[domain=-arcsinh(2):arcsinh(2)] ({2*cosh(\x)},{2*sinh(\x)}) 
                node[midway,right, yshift=1.2ex, xshift=2.9em] {$r=2$}; 
            \draw [color=green] plot[domain=-arcsinh(4/3):arcsinh(4/3)] ({3*cosh(\x)},{3*sinh(\x)}) 
                node[midway, yshift=1.2ex, xshift=10em] {$r=3$}; 
            \draw [color=black] plot[domain=0:4/tanh(1)] ({\x},{tanh(1)*\x}) node[right] {$\omega=1$};  
            \filldraw ({cosh(1)},{sinh(1)}) circle (2pt); 
            \filldraw ({2*cosh(1)},{2*sinh(1)}) circle (2pt); 
            \filldraw ({3*cosh(1)},{3*sinh(1)}) circle (2pt);   
        \end{tikzpicture}   
    }  
    \caption{\label{fig:Hyperbolas}Polar Coordinates in a Minkowski Space}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]